# Youtube The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

My Application shows quota limit exceeding error for Youtube V3 API.
My daily limit in Google console is 0. This value I cannot change.
How fix this?

[image: screen]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions seeking for help related to the Google Developers console should instead either contact support or ask in the relevant support forum. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for additional info.

Comment: @Edric not exactly sure i would qualify this as customer service related.  THis is configuration related to usage of the YouTube api and why we have a Google-developers-console tag.

Answer (score 3):

Click the little pencil icon next to the `0` and increase it to 10000.  If you still get the error message after that, you will need to apply for a quota extension.

If you get an error when attempting that, it's because you need to apply for quota first.

## Quota extension application.

Go to https://console.developers.google.com/ for your project

- library
- search for YouTube Data
- click manage button
- click quota menu
- click quota page link
- click a quota and select edit quota at the top.

A panel will open on the side

[image]

You can apply for 10k more but it's going to take some time.  It took me three months to get an extension of 10k

Comment: I did it. Was show error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q98bo.jpg

Comment: Then you will need to apply for a quota extension before you can begin using the API.

Comment: I cannot apply quota extension. Cannot enter more than 0

Comment: Unfortunately i cant read the text on your image but iif it doesn't translate to **Submit Request** then you are in the wrong place.   You are probably in the change the quota form not the request additional quota form.

Comment: English screen: http://joxi.ru/bmoRg1Btyxpyer?d=1

Comment: Did you click the "apply for higher quota link" in that picture?

Comment: Yes. And it shows an error. I can write only 0 there

Comment: Try again tomorrow there may be a bug.  or try the other one you apear to have two rows listed as **queries per day** on the left of your picture.

Comment: I've been trying it for 5 days((( From 30.10 http://joxi.ru/zANMW9QCjBpK82?d=1

Comment: I would submit an issue on the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B

Comment: If anyone is still having the issue, I found that adding a billing account to your project helps. Here's more info: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project